# command prompt shortcut difference "." and "../.."

Tags: java, command-line

What is the difference between the following three commands:-

1) `javac -cp "." com.company.Test.class`

2) `javac -cp "../.." com.company.Test.class`

3) `javac  com.company.Test.class`

Also, is there any difference in each command for javac and java, I mean if I use 1 statement for javac and java command so is there any difference.

Comment: What do you mean with your second question? Can you rephrase it or explain it more? It sounds like if you are asking for the difference between `javac.exe` and `java.exe`. The first compiles java code and generates byte code out of it, the `.class` files. The second executes the byte code.

Comment: I mean to say is there any difference if I use "." command with javac and java 

Javac "."  test.java
Java "."  com.company.Test

Comment: I am very sorry but I still don't get it. However, after you have already received a good answer, is there still something left unanswered? If so, please edit your question (instead of posting a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling :-

CASE 1 :- Compiling a single program / .java file :-

Program :-

```
package com.bharat;

    class Test{
static int x =10;
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println(x+" "+"Class Test");
}

}
```

Directory :-

C:/com/bharat

Commands :-

```
1)C:\com\bharat>javac Test.java

2)C:>\javac -cp “.” com/bharat/Test.java

3)C:>\javac -cp “../..” com/bharat/Test.java
```

CASE 2 :- Two programs, with second program using an object of first program :-

Program 1:-

```
package com.bharat;

class Test{
static int x =10;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        System.out.println(x+" "+"Class Test");
}

}
```

Program 2 :-

```
package com.bharat;

class Test2{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println(Test.x+" "+"Class Test2");
}

}
```

Directory :- C:/com/bharat

Commands :-

```
1)C:/com/bharat>javac -cp “.” *.java
2)C:/com/bharat>javac -cp “../..” *.java
3)C:/com/bharat>javac Test.java
4)C:/com/bharat>javac Test2.java
```

:- Error :-

Cannot find symbol Test.x because it searches for x in com/bharat/com/bharat

5)C:/com/bharat>javac -cp “.” Test2.java :- Error :-

Cannot find symbol Test.x because it searches for x in com/bharat/com/bharat

6)C:/com/bharat>javac -cp “../..” Test2.java

Works fine because now because of “../..” it searches for x in root directory (C:) i.e. C:/com/bharat

```
7)C:\>javac -cp "." com/bharat/test2.java
8)C:\>javac -cp "../.." com/bharat/test2.java
```

Running :-

```
1)C:\com\bharat>java -cp "." com.bharat.Test -          Error
2)C:\com\bharat>java -cp "../.." com.bharat.Test
3)C:\com\bharat>java -cp "." com.bharat.Test2 -             Error
4)C:\com\bharat>java -cp "../.." com.bharat.Test2
5)C:\>java com.bharat.Test
6)C:\>java com.bharat.Test2
7)C:\>java -cp "." com.bharat.Test
8)C:\>java -cp "." com.bharat.Test2
9)C:\>java -cp "../.." com.bharat.Test2
10)C:\>java -cp "../.." com.bharat.Test
```

CASE 3 :-
Compiling and running two programs with different packages :-

Location:-

Program :-

1)

```
package comm.Pack1;

public class Test{
public static int x =10;
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println(x+" "+"Class Test");
}

}
```

2)

```
 package comm.Pack2;
import comm.Pack1.Test;
class Test2{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println(Test.x+" "+"Class Test2");
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

1) `"."` means current folder, so **javac** will find `com.company.Test.class` in the **current folder**.

2) `".."` means **parent folder**, `"../.."` means current folder's parent folder's parent folder.

3) javac without `-cp` means find file in **current folder**. Equals to *1)*.

Comment: Let's extend the answer. `javac` is a program that takes arguments. In your case, OP, you first use the argument `-cp` which stands for *classpath*. That `-cp` command now also wants an argument, a path to where the classpath should be set to. In your case this is exactly the `"."` stuff. After `-cp` is finished the next argument for `javac` comes, this are the *source files* you want to compile. The official documentation can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Also note that the `java` program has a very similar syntax compared to `javac`. Its documentation is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html. And note that this `"."` and `"../.."` stuff is nothing that comes from the **Java** language. That is stuff that comes from your **operating system** (or to be more precise, the shell you work with, for example Windows **cmd**).